# Can the filter be set to a default value? (ex:Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = x => true)

Tags: c#

what i want to do is:
if there is no filter, fetch all the data. if there is a filter, filter and fetch

is there a way to assign a value for the filter like this?
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZZrx.png)

```
public static List<Test> getAllExpression<Func<Test, bool>> filter = x => true)
    {           
        return context.Test.FromSqlRaw($"Select *from {tableName}").Where(filter).ToList();
    }
```

i tried and got the error:The default parameter value for "filter " must be a compile-time constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the default value of `filter` to `null` and then use

```
public static List<Test> getAll(Expression<Func<Test, bool>> filter = null)
{
    Expression<Func<Test, bool>> defaultFilter = x => true;           
    return context.Test.FromSqlRaw($"Select * from {tableName}").Where(filter ?? defaultFilter).ToList();
}
```

Even better would be to not *have* a filter in the first place when it's not needed:

```
public static List<Test> getAll(Expression<Func<Test, bool>> filter = null)
{
    var query = context.Test.FromSqlRaw($"Select * from {tableName}");
    if(filter != null) 
    {
         query = query.Where(filter);
    }
    return query.ToList();
}
```